# Storing json string in Hadoop file with delimiter

Tags: java, hadoop

I am converting object into json string and storing it into hadoop file system with each string is seperated by some delimter.

```
FSDataOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConfiguration);

            out = fs.exists(outFile) ? fs.append(outFile) : fs.create(outFile);
            ConnTrackInfo conntrack = new ConnTrackInfo(124, "ranjeet@triconinfotec.com", "instrutor", new Date(), "Section", 234,"Economics",9991, "EZT", "124XSD234", 33, "GeneralEconomics", "192.168.1.210");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String jsonstring = null;
            jsonstring = gson.toJson(conntrack);

            out.writeUTF(jsonstring.concat("@@@"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Unable to persist tracking data", e);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
```

It is storing data fine but its adds some extra digits with my delimiter.
my file data is like this

```
1{"userId":124,"emailId":"ranjeet@triconinfotec.com","role":"instrutor","date":"Jul 30, 2014 11:56:12 AM","target":"Section","sectionId":234,"sectionName":"Economics","assignmentId":9991,"assignmentName":"EZT","isbn":"124XSD234","courseId":33,"courseName":"GeneralEconomics","ipaddress":"192.168.1.210"}@@@1{"userId":124,"emailId":"ranjeet@triconinfotec.com","role":"instrutor","date":"Jul 30, 2014 11:56:55 AM","target":"Section","sectionId":234,"sectionName":"Economics","assignmentId":9991,"assignmentName":"EZT","isbn":"124XSD234","courseId":33,"courseName":"GeneralEconomics","ipaddress":"192.168.1.210"}@@@1{"userId":124,"emailId":"ranjeet@triconinfotec.com","role":"instrutor","date":"Jul 30, 2014 12:15:02 PM","target":"Section","sectionId":234,"sectionName":"Economics","assignmentId":9991,"assignmentName":"EZT","isbn":"124XSD234","courseId":33,"courseName":"GeneralEconomics","ipaddress":"192.168.1.210"}@@@1{"userId":124,"emailId":"ranjeet@triconinfotec.com","role":"instrutor","date":"Jul 30, 2014 12:18:25 PM","target":"Section","sectionId":234,"sectionName":"Economics","assignmentId":9991,"assignmentName":"EZT","isbn":"124XSD234","courseId":33,"courseName":"GeneralEconomics","ipaddress":"192.168.1.210"}@@@1{"userId":124,"emailId":"ranjeet@triconinfotec.com","role":"instrutor","date":"Jul 30, 2014 12:19:23 PM","target":"Section","sectionId":234,"sectionName":"Economics","assignmentId":9991,"assignmentName":"EZT","isbn":"124XSD234","courseId":33,"courseName":"GeneralEconomics","ipaddress":"192.168.1.210"}@@@0{"userId":124,"emailId":"ranjeet@triconinfotec.com","role":"instrutor","date":"Jul 30, 2014 12:22:37 PM","target":"Section","sectionId":234,"sectionName":"Economics","assignmentId":9991,"assignmentName":"EZT","isbn":"124XSD234","courseId":33,"courseName":"GeneralEconomics","ipaddress":"192.168.1.210"}
```

If you see 1st line it write my data after 1so later all my data has delimiter @@@1 but i don;t want this 1 here. I am nw to Hadoop and i need solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `writeUTF` method, it writes data in modified UTF-8 encoding as it says [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html?is-external=true#writeUTF(java.lang.String)). Try to use `PrintWriter`:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out);
pw.println(jsonstring + "@@@");
pw.close();
```